# Is Chromium known for bugs with Bootstrap/Laravel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, chromium

I am having trouble with my Bootstrap/Laravel website.

I have a simple navbar at the top, with a logo and a dropdown button menu.

The button menu is positioned perfectly, apart from on the sign in page, where it seems it is forced to move down a line. The problem is, the fact that I am using Laravel layout views, the view should be exactly the same apart from the content that I submit using @section('content').

Now the weird bit, if I target my site using Firefox, it's fine... Just using Chromium, and only on my "sign in" page.

Here is some code, which personally I see nothing wrong with.

Navigation Layout

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="londrina inline">WEBSITE NAME</h1>
    <div class="floatright aligntop">
        @if(Auth::check())
        <h4 class="hideforsmall inline">Logged in as {{ Auth::user()->username }}&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>
        @endif

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:200px;">
                <span class="floatleft glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span><div class="floatright">@if(!isset($active)){{ "Navigation" }}@else{{ $active }}@endif <span class="caret"></span></div>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="visible-xs btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius:5px;font-size:25px;">
                <span class="floatleft glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu navdropdownmenu" role="menu">
                <?php if(!isset($active)){$active='empty';} ?>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'Home'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                @if(Auth::check())
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'My Claims'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('account-claims') }}">My Claims</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'Archive'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('account-archive') }}">Archive</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'Energy'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('energy-home') }}">Energy</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-sign-out') }}">Sign Out</a></li>
                @if(Auth::user()->admin)
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'Admin'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('account-admin') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
                @endif
                @else
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'Sign In'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('account-sign-in') }}">Sign In</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($active == 'Sign Up'){echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="{{ URL::route('account-create') }}">Sign Up</a></li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sign In

```
    @extends('layout.main')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
        <div class="jumbotron signinheight">
                <h1>Existing Members</h1>
                <p class="text-center">Remember to follow the <a href="http://www.URLHERE.org">WEBSITE HERE</a> process to the end. Turn the tables, claim all bills owed to you!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
        <div class="panel panel-primary signinheight signinbox">
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <form class="text-center" method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('account-sign-in-post') }}" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email"@if($errors->has('email')){{ ' style="background-color:#ffaaaa;"' }}@endif>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password"@if($errors->has('password')){{ ' style="background-color:#ffaaaa;"' }}@endif>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Sign In</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                {{ Form::token() }}
            </form>
            <h2>Forgotten it?</h2>
            <form class="text-center" method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('account-forgot-password-post') }}" role="form">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email_forgot"@if($errors->has('email_forgot')){{ ' style="background-color:#ffaaaa;"' }}@endif>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Forgot Password</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                {{ Form::token() }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Main Layout

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>WEBSITE NAME</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css'); }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/introanim.css'); }}
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Outline' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    {{ HTML::style('css/animate.css'); }}

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    @include('layout.navigation')
    @if (Session::has('success')) {{ '<div class="alert alert-success adjustalertboxsignin alertmarginbottom">' . Session::get('success') . '</div>' }} @endif
    @if (Session::has('warning')) {{ '<div class="alert alert-warning adjustalertboxsignin alertmarginbottom">' . Session::get('warning') . '</div>' }} @endif
    @yield('content')
    @include('layout.footer')
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="{{ public_path() }}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post screenshots? Do you have a working example of that site?

Comment: I've personally had problems/weirdness with font sizes on Chromium and Chrome on windows. It might be unrelated, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Example is here - http://i61.tinypic.com/sb3muw.jpg